# Kubernetes : container "kubedns" in pod "kube-dns-86f4d74b45-whjqd" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I am running into below issue.

```sh
Kubernetes cannot pull kube-dns (k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.8) image from our private registry, but pulling other images works fine (image like k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64:1.14.8).
```

- `$ kubectl -n kube-system get pods`

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper-76485f9dc-cj2lk   0/1     Pending            0          2h
etcd-serverhostname                         1/1     Running            1          2h
kube-apiserver-serverhostname               1/1     Running            1          2h
kube-controller-manager-serverhostname      1/1     Running            1          2h
--> kube-dns-86f4d74b45-whjqd                   1/3     ImagePullBackOff   54         2h**
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-26tqx                 1/1     Running            0          2h
kube-proxy-m2cq2                            1/1     Running            0          2h
kube-scheduler-serverhostname               1/1     Running            1          2h
kubernetes-dashboard-684b746f46-xtjcd       0/1     Pending            0          2h
```

- `$ kubectl logs kube-dns-86f4d74b45-whjqd -c kubedns  --namespace=kube-system`

```sh
Error from server (BadRequest): container "kubedns" in pod "kube-dns-86f4d74b45-whjqd" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

- `$ kubectl describe pod kube-dns-86f4d74b45-whjqd  --namespace=kube-system`

```sh
...
  Normal   Created                54m                  kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Created container
  Normal   Started                54m                  kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Started container
  Normal   Pulling                53m (x2 over 55m)    kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.8"
  Warning  Failed                 52m (x2 over 54m)    kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed                 52m (x3 over 54m)    kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Warning  Unhealthy              52m (x5 over 53m)    kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
  Normal   Killing                25m (x8 over 51m)    kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Killing container with id docker://dnsmasq:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  Failed                 15m (x10 over 54m)   kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Failed to pull image "k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.8": rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
  Warning  BackOff                10m (x68 over 40m)   kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   BackOff                10s (x190 over 54m)  kubelet, lcicd01.nms.ld  Back-off pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.8"
```

Comment: Hello. Please update your question with steps of how you installed your Kubernetes cluster. Which CNI are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue.
The root cause was that when I prepulled and tagged the image I didn't use the right tag.
I used k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.8 instead of k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.8.
I forgot the prefix.
Since, I added it in the tag, it works fine.

We can close the case and mark it as resolved.

Thank you a lot for your help.